# Modern day dharma - parents vs wife?

Tags: puranas, dharma

I have read Ramayana and I know little bit about Bhagavad gita. In these, as per dharma, parents wishes and promises are more important than wife. And this might be acceptable in those days because women's dharma was to follow husband. (Correct me if I am wrong)

But in today's modern world, everyone prefer equal rights to women and their wishes also should be honoured.

So, when there is a conflict between parents and wife, what decision a man should make as per dharma, if both are correct from their perspective?

Is there any Purana addresses this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So, when there is a conflict between parents and wife, what decision a
>   man should make as per dharma, if both are correct from their
>   perspective?

If we follow Manu Smriti then we have to listen to what the parents say. But again nothing specific, because none of the verses given below take into account the wife and your specific problem.

> Manu Smriti 2.227. That trouble (and pain) which the parents undergo
>   on the birth of (their) children, cannot be compensated even in a
>   hundred years.
>
> 2.228. **Let him always do what is agreeable to those (two)** and always (what may please) his teacher; when those three are pleased, he
>   obtains all (those rewards which) austerities (yield).
>
> 2.235. **As long as those three live, so long let him not (independently) perform any other (meritorious acts); let him always
>   serve them, rejoicing (to do what is) agreeable and beneficial (to
>   them).**
>
> 2.236. **He shall inform them of everything that with their consent he may perform** in thought, word, or deed for the sake of the next world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is why, sometimes I feel the dharma should be altered for modern times. 

Comment: You are welcome @Selva. Some dharmas do change with time. But some remain the same all through out. Specially the parents relation with us must remain the same. Also there is a particular Smriti called the Parashara Smriti . It is specially applicable to Kali Yuga. It says women dominating over men is one of the salient (bad) features of this Yuga.