# Disobeying the parents

Tags: bhishma, mahabharata

I think bhishma did a big mistake by not disobeying his father and taking a lifelong vow of celibacy. Had he confronted his father at the right moment this whole war could have been stopped.

Was it so important for bhishma to serve his father's lust ?

If he was so wise couldn't he identify that his father was running for lust which can bring devastating consequences?

Does Krishna in any of the scriptures (or any other scriptures) mention that we should not obey our parents blindly?

Comment: Ya , you can read  the  chapter 2  of Gita.  Don't be too much attachment to  your parent, you will  lose your true nature  because attachement bring bondage. Lord krishna also say  tumhare papa(father) phele janam mein kiye te aur agla  janam  mein kya hoga  yeh kisi ko pata  nhi  isliye  don't be too much attachement your parents  otherwise  you will not  become spiritual.For example read the biography  of Milarepa , Lord budhha and Meera...they  have break up  with their parent for spiritual knowlegde .Also  Krishna say that be like  lotus flower  don't make any attachement

Comment: Your question includes multiple questions, guidelines ask for each posting to be limited to one question. Also, some are asking for opinions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modern day dharma - parents vs wife?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18201/modern-day-dharma-parents-vs-wife)